# Пытаюсь подключить mySQL к intellij idea

Tags: mysql, база-данных, intellij-idea

Пытаюсь подключить mySQL к intellij idea с помощью DB Navigator. При попытке подключиться, мне выдает ошибку:
"Cannot connect to "Connection".
The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support."[image: ошибка]
Настройку defult-time-zone я поставил но ошибка осталась! В чем может быть проблема? [image: Настройки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была с версией DB Navigator, после установки старой версии проблема пропала.

Comment: как вы установили старую верию?

Comment: Вот отсюда: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator/versions